# action bar not showing options menu in jelly bean

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.1-jelly-bean

Action bar does not show options menu in jelly bean,while it is shown in lollipop.
here is my styles.xml`

```
 <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00796B</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#004D40</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#c51162</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark</item>


</style>


 </resources>`
```

here is my app gradle

```
 compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dell.syncytium"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
   }
```

My MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity.
please help me.thanks in advance

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, logoutMenu, 0, "Logout");
    menu.add(0,Play,1,"Play Music");
    menu.add(0,Stop,2,"Stop Music");
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Does the mobile has menu buttons as soft keys or physical keys?

Comment: it has soft keys.on pressing the menu soft key,options menu is shown,but i need the three dots menu in action bar.

Comment: Phones with hardware menu button's doesn't show the overflow menu icon (3 dotted icon). That's the reason I asked.  Try to post the code related to `onCreateOptionMenu`

Comment: '@Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, logoutMenu, 0, "Logout");
        menu.add(0,Play,1,"Play Music");
        menu.add(0,Stop,2,"Stop Music");
        return result;
           }'

Comment: I updated the code with onCreateOptionsMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

menu.xml

```
<menu 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
 tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/connect_scan"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
<item android:id="@+id/discoverable"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu:
         break;
        case R.id.discoverable:
         break;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can make menu from your activity itself without menu.xml file but it will provide you single option on action bar.....

Try this..

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ---- //

 }
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 1, 1, "New");
        menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Create");
        menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Open");
        menu.add(0, 4, 4, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, 5, 5, "Exit");

        return true;
    }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case (1):
           //----//
            return true;
        case (2):
           //---//
            return true;
        case (3):
           //---//
            return true;
        case (4):
            //---//
            return true;
        case (5):
            finish();
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

OutPut

[image]

Comment: I did the same thing,it worked for lollipop,but the threedots is not seen in jelly bean mobile.

Comment: thanks for your concern ,i vill try both the answers again and inform if it works.

Comment: if it do not show, then download and put an image (threedots) in drawable folder and use it as icon...

Comment: yeah i did so.Thank you mohit @mohit